# Array confusion

Tags: java, arrays

I am not a get programmer and I have been having problems with my code. 
I get the error:

```
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`
```

Some help will be appreciated. Thank you.

My code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Gradebook1D {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] id = new int[0];
    double[] quiz1 = new double[0];
    double[] quiz2 = new double[0];
    double[] quiz3 = new double[0];

    int idStudent = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter how student's are in your class: ");
    idStudent = input.nextInt();

    double[] sum = new double[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < idStudent; i++){
      System.out.println("Enter student ID: ");
      id[i] = input.nextInt();

      System.out.print("\n Enter score for Quiz1: ");
      quiz1[i] = input.nextInt();

      System.out.print("\n Enter score for Quiz2: ");
      quiz2[i] = input.nextInt();

      System.out.print("\n Enter score for Quiz3: ");
      quiz3[i] = input.nextInt();

      sum[i] = quiz1[i] + quiz2[i] + quiz3[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `new int[0]`, `new double[0]` means Zero size!

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I did not know I had to get the input first then initialize the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting with an array of zero size when doing `new int[0]`, new double[0], etc... Try setting the array size after you know how long it needs to be:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter how student's are in your class: ");
int idStudent = input.nextInt();

int[] id = new int[idStudent];
double[] quiz1 = new double[idStudent];
double[] quiz2 = new double[idStudent];
double[] quiz3 = new double[idStudent];
double[] sum = new double[idStudent];

for (int i = 0; i < idStudent; i++){
  //Now all arrays have size idStudent so 'i' will be in bounds
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know you had to get the input first then initialize the arrays.

Comment: There is another option, which is to use a List object instead of an Array. Lists are used if you don't know the size at runtime or the size grows over time; However, it is a more advanced topic.

Answer (score 2):

initialize `id` ,`quiz1`, `quiz2`, `quiz3` with `idStudent` like this

```
int[] id = new int[idStudent];
double[] quiz1 = new double[idStudent];
double[] quiz2 = new double[idStudent];
double[] quiz3 = new double[idStudent];
```

the reason for that error is you declaring array with zero size. you can't insert element to an array with zero size

Answer (score 1):

Not the best Java programmer, but I am almost positive you are setting the array size to 0 with the [0].

```
int [ ] nums = new int [ 8 ];
for(int ctr = 0; ctr < 8; ctr++)
{
  //logic here       
}
```

would be an example of how to do a correct array.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize an array, you must *specify its length*. When you do

```
int[] id = new int[0];
```

you are specifying that array will have length `0`. So you can't even access its first element (by using `id[0]`)

You can initialize it, for example, in the following way

```
int[] id = new int[4]; // length 4
```

but since you are getting an input that represents the number of students, I guess it will be the length of the arrays:

```
int[] id = new int[idStudent];
```

but, you will have to do this *after* you have received the input.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating an Array of size 0. Hence, there are no "slots" in the array, so when you try to reference a slot, it gets out of bounds. If you want a "flexible" size array, where you can add elements easily, use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
int[] id = new int[size thats you require];
```

instead of

```
int[] id = new int[0];
```

hope you will get your solution